# Getting Connection refused error when using scp on VM

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have a virtual linux build running on qemu (It runs drop bear as ssh client.) and I am trying to copy some modules I wrote to it using scp using the following command:

```
    scp -vvv -p 2222 wd/day10/int_mod.ko root@localhost:/lib/modules/3.13.5/int_mod.ko
```

And I get Connection refused error more specifically (I forwarded 2222 to 22 of virtual machine.):

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host localhost, user root, command scp -v -p -d -t /lib/modules/3.13.5/int_mod.ko
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

What I don't understand is I can easily connect to ssh using

```
   ssh -p 2222 root@localhost
```

I can connect without any problem.

Answer (score 8):

ssh and scp use different options for specifying the port. From the ssh man page:

```
[-p port]
```

From the scp man page:

```
[-P port]
```

scp uses capital P. Notice how your debug output says port 22 connection refused when you are trying to connect to port 2222.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that , `ssh` package is not installed completely!
you must install `ssh` and `openssh-client` so on... with Synaptic Package Manager!

in Synaptic Package Manager , first type `ssh` in search filter and mark `ssh`. then click on Apply Button to install ssh services for server and client.

by this way your problem will fixed 100 Percentage!!!
see bellow Please:

[image: Install Synaptic Package Manager then increase next steps...]